# How to deal with Lexical or processsor issue

Tags: ios, swift

Lexical or Preprocessor Issue

> FMDatabase.h file not found
>   SFSmartStoreUpgrade.m

and

> FMDatabase.h file not found
>   SFSmartStoreDatabaseManager.m

Is shown immediately after the build in Xcode

How to resolve it?

Comment: The issue is `FMDatabase.h file not found`. please add `FMDatabase.h` file in to your project. This file is being used in your project

Comment: you have this file in project?

Comment: Yes... I have, these files in my project

Comment: not found is mostly related with xcode could not file your file, see if .m file is added in target or not, and .h file exist on relevant  path